# useEffect used for countdown timer, re-renders whole page each second

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React app, I created countdown timer:

```
  const [showSec, setShowSec] = useState(15);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer =
      showSec > 0 && setInterval(() => setShowSec(showSec - 1), 1000);
    if (showSec === 0) {
      setShowEnterCode(false);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [showSec]);
```

I show it like that:

```
<span>{showSec}</span>
```

and in another place in my code I have something like this for showing some errors:

```
  {props.args.errorFormat === 2 ? (
     <ErrorSnackBar args={ErrorSnackbarArgs} />
  ) : (
     <></>
  )}
```

But my problem is that, every time that countdown counts, this part of code executes again. It seems re rendering happens. for example when that condition is `true`, It should show an error with `Material-UI`'s `SnackBar` but because of that countdown timer, it restart showing the error constantly. I cant prevent this issue. what I have to do?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Either: use a separate component for your countdown so its state changing doesn't re-render more than the actual countdown, or: introduce a state to keep track of whether you've already shown the snackbar.

Comment: Really recommend you to use this custom hook from Dan Abramov himself, I'm using it on the project I'm working on and it works great
https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code, it has Timer as pure component and you can pass in `setShowEnterCode` and optionally `seconds`. Make sure that `setShowEnterCode` in App does not change when App re renders:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

//make this a pure component so it won't re render when props
//  don't change and parent re renders. It re renders when
//  local state changes
const Timer = React.memo(function Timer({
  setShowEnterCode,
  seconds = 15,
}) {
  const [showSec, setShowSec] = useState(seconds);
  //you can pass in seconds (default is 15) and it'll
  //  set the initial duration
  useEffect(() => setShowSec(seconds), [seconds]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer =
      showSec > 0 &&
      //effect runs every time showSec changes so
      //  no need for the interval it only runs once
      setTimeout(() => setShowSec(showSec - 1), 1000);
    if (showSec === 0) {
      setShowEnterCode(false);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
    //make sure setShowEnterCode does not change
    //  when App re renders
  }, [setShowEnterCode, showSec]);
  return <span>{showSec}</span>;
});

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(1);
  const [showEnterCode, setShowEnterCode] = React.useState(
    true
  );
  //this effect causes App to re render 10 times a second
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const i = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((c) => c + 1);
    }, 100);
    return () => clearInterval(i);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>app counter:{count}</div>
      {showEnterCode && (
        <Timer setShowEnterCode={setShowEnterCode} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```